# Why my computer goes to sleep when I connect any USB device?

Tags: linux-mint, usb, hardware

I have a Linux Mint 19 laptop model Gateway NV51M.

It happens when I connect ANY device, from USB Pen drives to USB Printers, in any USB port.

The problem started a few months ago, I didn't touch anything in configuration. I keep my laptop up-to-date.

Any idea of how can I solve it?

Comment: Seems more a hw issue than a Unix question.

Comment: Did you check for odd `udev` rules (or events in your syslog)?

Comment: Does `dmesg -w` report anything?

Comment: Does this happen with other Linux distributions?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I tried live USB on another distros and I've had no troubles.. So I may solve the problem by reinstalling the distro (or may not) but I want to find a solution without to recur on it.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro it's not a hardware issue as it happens only with this os.

Comment: @confetti sorry. I did dmesg -w and it reports lots of things I don't really understand. But I haven't seen "error" reports

Comment: @LucasGamaleri is there anything printed in red? if yes or if you see anything related to USB, it might help adding the log by [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/478431/edit) your question. Ideally, you first start `dmesg -w` and then plug something in, and only focus on the new lines which appear.

Comment: @LucasGamaleri Well, if it only happens with this distribution, then it should be possible to track down what is going wrong, since it is then presumably a software issue. But it may not be very easy. I would try installing the distribution that Linux Mint 19 most closely inherits from, either Debian or Ubuntu, because if that works ok, it will be easier to figure out what is going on, since the differences would be comparatively minor.

Comment: @confetti I started dmesg -w, then plugged an USB drive in (that also usually sends my laptop to sleep) and nothing printed in red. And my computer didn't sleep while doing that.